# How to open a browser tab and track it's activities using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in which i have created a JavaScript function where, and i have saved 10 URLs in an array. Now i want to have a `onclick` event on some button, which when clicked should call a function in which we pass that URLs array as parameter.

What i want is, the function should be able to open a new tab in the current browser, visit each of the URL one by one for 2 minutes and return progress like Which one is being visited, how many already visited etc to it's parent page?

Is it possible? I'm not able to frame a logic of how this can be achieved, may be using JavaScript or jQuery?

Please suggest.

Regards

Comment: Browsers won't share that sort of information, in general.

Comment: Not possible. Browsers will not give you that kind of information. What may work however, is if you create a browser extension that will monitor your activity

Comment: While you can't use tabs, you can use an `<iframe>` and assign to the `onload` event handler of the element - this will allow you to know that the page has been loaded, but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for the Client Side as JS cant look in to browser functionality.
The URL progess in sense you are looking in to load or any results then you can look in to server side calls like CURL API or AJAX Call.

-

1. AJAX Call: This API you can use to any of the divs in the current HTML Page itself and create update functon which is called and updates the load precentage of the loading and you can display the same to div.

   - Update function can be called using ajax object with event listener to it where it takes

   > var percentValue = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;